# mysql, count distinct values between two tables (V2)

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA  
(ID_A INT,   
 P1 INT,
 P2 INT,
 P3 INT,
 P4 INT,
 Nr1 INT,
 Nr2 INT,
 Nr3 INT,
 Nr4 INT);

INSERT INTO TableA VALUES
(1,3,4,3,5,2,3,1,4),
(2,5,4,3,4,1,1,1,2);

CREATE TABLE TableB
(ID_B INT,
NAME TEXT);

INSERT INTO TableB VALUES
(1,"A"),
(2,"B"),
(3,"C"),
(4,"D"),
(5,"E"),
(6,"F");
```

Values in Tables

```
TableA
+------+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+-----+
| ID_A | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4  | Nr1| Nr2| Nr3| Nr4 |
+------+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+-----+
|    1 |  3 |  4 |  3 |   5 |  2 |  3 |  1 |  4  |
|    2 |  5 |  4 |  3 |   4 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  2  |
+------+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+-----+

TableB
+------+------+
| ID_B | Name |
+------+------+
|    1 | A    |
|    2 | B    |
|    3 | C    |
|    4 | D    |
|    5 | E    |
|    6 | F    |
+------+------+
```

tableA P1 = TableB ID_B ,

tableA P2 = TableB ID_B ,

tableA P3 = TableB ID_B ,

tableA P4 = TableB ID_B

I want the sum of all the names in TableB that correspond in P1, P2, P3, P4;   while Nr1, Nr2, Nr3, Nr4 is the quantity:

P1 =SUM Nr1

P2 =SUM Nr2

P3 =SUM Nr3

P4 =SUM Nr4

I want to get this:

```
+----------+------+
| COUNT(*) | Name |
+----------+------+
|        4 | C    |
|        6 | D    |
|        5 | E    |
+----------+------+
```

[My DEMO db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nRpqNiUmpRVJJ4gMP66Ywn/11)

The demo does not add up Nr.

Thanks to those who will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle you are not selecting the corresponding Nr1/2/3/4 value. Add them to the select clause and sum them:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Val)
FROM (
    SELECT TableB.Name, TableA.Nr1 AS Val FROM TableA JOIN TableB ON TableA.P1 = TableB.ID_B UNION ALL
    SELECT TableB.Name, TableA.Nr2 AS Val FROM TableA JOIN TableB ON TableA.P2 = TableB.ID_B UNION ALL
    SELECT TableB.Name, TableA.Nr3 AS Val FROM TableA JOIN TableB ON TableA.P3 = TableB.ID_B UNION ALL
    SELECT TableB.Name, TableA.Nr4 AS Val FROM TableA JOIN TableB ON TableA.P4 = TableB.ID_B
) AS x
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.
I have to check with the real database if the values are correct.
I also have DATE in TableA
Do I have to use it like this?

    SELECT TableB.Name, TableA.Nr1 AS Val, TableA.dateEND
    FROM TableA JOIN TableB ON TableA.P1 = TableB.ID_B 
    UNION ALL
   ... ecc
    WHERE (dateEND >= '2019-01-01'   AND    dateEND <= '2019-04-30')

Comment: Yes, you can add the date to the inner select clause and use it in the where clause outside.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want to do this without needing a subquery:

```
  SELECT Name, 
         SUM(IF(P1 = ID_B, Nr1, 0) +
             IF(P2 = ID_B, Nr2, 0) +
             IF(P3 = ID_B, Nr3, 0) +
             IF(P4 = ID_B, Nr4, 0))
    FROM TableA
    JOIN TableB ON (TableA.P1 = TableB.ID_B
                    OR TableA.P2 = TableB.ID_B
                    OR TableA.P3 = TableB.ID_B
                    OR TableA.P4 = TableB.ID_B)
GROUP BY Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use  a select UNION ALL and group by

```
  select t2.name, count(*)
  from TableB t2
  inner join  (
  select  p1 p 
  from TableA 
  union all 
  select  p2
  from TableA 
  union all 
  select  p3
  from TableA 
  union all 
  select  p4
  from TableA 
  ) t on t.p = t2.ID_B
  group t2.name
  order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: Thanks for writing.
I tried your code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: you show Demo page:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nRpqNiUmpRVJJ4gMP66Ywn/11

Comment: I think the alias was set wrongly. It suppose to be `TableB t2`, not `TableA t2`. And forgot to add `BY` at the grouping. Once that is corrected, this query works very well. However, its missing the OP condition where it need to add up `Nr%` quantity.